# VBA "Sum and merge" a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, merge, sum

I want to get a sum based on the criteria of the preceding column data. Suppose I have three columns say A, B and C. So, "A" columns have the Sr.no. let's say, "B" has the quantity and "C" have the total quantity. I am trying to sum the quantity in column "B" based on the Sr.no. in column "A" and paste it to column "C" (after merging that many cells) against the respective Sr.no. (Which we have in column "A"). Refer image attached [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWMLI.png).

```
Sub sum_on_condition()

Dim sum_criteria As Double
Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long
Dim l_array As Variant
Dim l_number As Long


lastrow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
l_array = range("I2:I21").Value

counter = 1
While counter <= UBound(l_array)
    l_number = l_array(counter, 1)
    For x = 2 To lastrow
      If range("e" & x).Value = l_number Then
        sum_criteria = sum_criteria + range("f" & x).Value
        
        End If
 
    Next x
counter = counter + 1
Wend
        
    Debug.Print sum_criteria
    
    
End Sub

I have written this code but what it does it sums the total value rather than the individual value. I am not able to figure out how I do this!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
Sub SumAndMerge()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim firstItem As Long, lastItem As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim c As Range, d As Range
Dim valueToFind As String
Dim total As Long


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    'Get valueToFind
    valueToFind = ws.Cells(i, 1).value
    'Get range of cells with .Find : look up for first value and last value and get row number.
    With ws.Range("A" & i & ":" & "A" & lastRow)
        Set c = .Find(valueToFind, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        firstItem = c.Row - 1
        Set d = .Find(valueToFind, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        lastItem = d.Row
    End With
    'Get total
    total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("B" & firstItem & ":" & "B" & lastItem))
    'Assign total to first cell
    ws.Range("C" & firstItem).value = total
    'Merge cells
    ws.Range("C" & firstItem & ":" & "C" & lastItem).Merge
    'Go to lastItem to adapt the loop
    i = lastItem
Next i

End Sub
```

Gives the following output:

[image]

Rather than using an array, this macro aims at using the `Find` function. In a loop, we find the first value and the last value. We extract row numbers and then we can assign the total and finally merge cells.
This code can be improved by replacing harcoded `A`, `B` and `C`. But this gives you an example.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine but when I change the column range it is not working also not showing any error. Can you help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by changing the column range? Which column are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about "replacing the hardcoded A, B and C". Suppose I want to change it into column range than how can I change that?

Comment: Without any context, hard to say. But I would go with another loop or with `Union`.

Comment: Suppose I have the same above data in some other columns say "E, F & G" then what should I change in your code to get it done for the same output?

Comment: You can replace the columns of `lastRow` and `valueToFind` because they are iterating over the first column. And after, you would need to change the letters in the different `Range` functions.
To give you two other options, you could either loop in the first row until the last column and retrieve the column integer of the your different values or also make use of the `Find` function as mentioned in the code below. That way, the hardcoded `A`, `B` and `C` would become variables you could change based on your needs.